# bash script line replacement based on criteria

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script that logs connection status and runs as a cron job. If it gets an ip, it logs the time to the file.

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=$(wget htt://checkip.dyndns.org/ -q -O - |
grep -Eo '\<[[:digit:]]{1,3}(\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){3}\>')

echo $ip

if [ -n "$ip" ]
then
    echo 'connected:'$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %I:%M") >> /home/saad/offline_check
else
    echo 'disconnected:'$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %I:%M") >> /home/saad/offline_check
fi
```

This script will keep appending `connected:XXXX` to the file every 5 mins. I want it to write once & then do no further logging until a disconnect occurs. When the connection resumes, it should write the current connection time on a new line.

This is what I want:

```
connected:08-02-2014 08:30     #start, all connected timestamps after initial one ignored
disconnected:09-02-2014 08:35  #disconnection logged
connected:09-02-2014 17:31     #when connection resumes, timestamp logged, all subsequent ignored until disconnect
disconnected:11-02-2014 08:31
```

I can do this in python, but not in bash.

Comment: If you did so much in `bash` and can do it in `python`, I don't see any reason why you shouldn't be able to do it.  No?

Comment: I don't work in bash at all. This script is somebody else's. I'd have to learn the entire structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check for last line of log file before writing:

```
#!/bin/bash

ip=$(wget htt://checkip.dyndns.org/ -q -O - |
grep -Eo '\<[[:digit:]]{1,3}(\.[[:digit:]]{1,3}){3}\>')

# get the last line from log
line=$(tail -1 /home/saad/offline_check)

echo $ip

if [ -n "$ip" ]; then
    # if last line starts with "disconnected" OR is empty then write "connected" log
    [[ -z "$line" || "$line" == 'disconnected:'* ]] && \
            echo 'connected:'$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %I:%M") >> /home/saad/offline_check
else
    [[ "$line" == 'connected:'* ]] && echo 'disconnected:'$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %I:%M") >> /home/saad/offline_check
fi
```

Comment: For posterity, also edit the else statement to `[[ "$line" == 'connected:'* ]] && echo 'disconnected:'$(date +"%d-%m-%Y %I:%M") >> /home/saad/offline_check` to avoid overpopulating log with `disconnected` messages.